# How can I get my python script to read all values from a config file?

Tags: python

I have a couple of config files. One with some team names and the other with positions. Each one of my users will upload a file with teams and positions on them. The teams and positions must match what's in the config files otherwise an error will print. I can get the script to read only one value from each config file. It doesn't read the rest of the values. How can I get it to read all of the values in the config files?

Here are the two config files:
for teams:
    [Teams]
    teams = Barcelona, Bayern, Inter, Chelsea

for positions:

```
[Positions]

positions = striker, midfielder, defender, goalkeeper
```

Here is a sample text file:

```
Teams   Positions   User ID
Barcelona   goalkeeper  BCTG-F
Barcelona   striker BCTG-F
Bayern  defender    BCTG-F
Bayern  striker    BCTG-F
Inter   striker    BCTG-F
Inter   midfielder  BCTG-F
Chelsea midfielder  BCTG-F
Chelsea goalkeeper  BCTG-F
```

Here is the script:

```
#!usr/bin/python


from subprocess import *

import sys
import ConfigParser
import os
import csv
from sys import argv
script, user_id, team_file = argv



def main():

    #get the actions

    def teamCalls():
        actions = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
        actions.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/team.cfg')
        for section_name in actions.sections():
            for name, value in actions.items(section_name):

                return '%s' %(value)

    teamCalls()

   #get the object types

    def positionTypes():
        objects = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
        objects.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/position.cfg')
        for section_name in objects.sections():
            for name, value in objects.items(section_name):

                return '%s' % (value)

    positionTypes()

    # checking path to file and user id
    try:
            f = csv.reader(open(team_file, "rb"), delimiter='\t')
    except:  
            logging.error('No such file or directory. Please try again')
    else:
            for line in f: 
                for row in f:                                  
                    if user_id != row[2]:
                        print ("User ID is incorrect")                                                                                 
                    elif teamCalls() != row[0]:

                        print ("Wrong team")                                                                       
                    elif positionTypes() != row[1]:
                        print ("Position not valid")

                    else: 
                        print row

    finally:
        print "all error checks done!"






main()

sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have "return" on the inner most statement of your loops.  This will cause it to return immediately, without looping through the rest of the values.  If you want a list of values, you could do something like:

```
calls = []
for section_name in actions.sections():
    for name,value in actions.items(section_name):
       calls.append(str(value))  # same as '%s' % (value)
return calls
```

Comment: Okay I tried it this way, creating a calls variable, appending it and returning it and I still get the same results

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

for line in open('team.cfg','r'):
    list_fu = [ column for column in line.split() ]
    print(list_fu)

Output:

```
['Teams', 'Positions', 'User', 'ID']
['Barcelona', 'goalkeeper', 'BCTG-F']
['Barcelona', 'striker', 'BCTG-F']
['Bayern', 'defender', 'BCTG-F']
['Bayern', 'striker', 'BCTG-F']
['Inter', 'striker', 'BCTG-F']
['Inter', 'midfielder', 'BCTG-F']
['Chelsea', 'midfielder', 'BCTG-F']
['Chelsea', 'goalkeeper', 'BCTG-F']
```

if you want to read in those positions, you should now the column of the list EG -> Positions, so it is 1. now you catch the Teams and User with if conditions:

for line in list_fu[1]:
    if line == 'goalkeeper':
        print(line) #do what you want to do

Comment: Where are you putting this? In what function?

Comment: you use it while initialising the script? Afterwards you use the list to get your beloved returns via if closes and definitions ... maybe.